# Listing bluetooth device Issue

Tags: cordova, typescript, bluetooth, ionic2

**Scenario:**

Need to list the available Bluetooth devices. I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer) in my ionic 2 project.

```
BTPrinter.list(function(data){
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data); //list of printer in data array
},function(err){
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
})
```

This works perfectly fine. but i couldn't able to assign the value of `data` to my typescript variable.

**Snippet:**

```
btList: string[] = [];
...
this.btList = BTPrinter.list(function (data: string[]) {
   return data;
}); // not working
...
BTPrinter.list(function (data){
this.btList = data;
});// not working
...
BTPrinter.list(function (data){
data.foreach(element =>{
this.btList.push(element);
});
});// not working
```

I tried all these three and used alert to display the result, all three shows undefined or []

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The problem could be `this` try using arrow function as callback

Comment: Pretty sure this is a javascript scope issue. Could you add the complete class, you took the snippet from?

Comment: You can try assigning your scope like this: `var self = this` and within your function call `self.btList...`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. But i moved on to [different plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial). and everything works perfectly there. Thanks again.